# error with login page

Tags: php, authentication

I got this code and i get 2 errors in it. ive been going crazy for it for 2 days now and can figure it out. the admin account is activated in sql database is connected but it wont go past this screen.

> Notice: Undefined index: username in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\band\logincheck.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: _REMOTE_ADDR in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\band\logincheck.php on line 13

wrong username/password combination or account not yet activated

```html
<?php
session_start();
header("Cache-control: private");
include 'includes/db_connect.php';



if (!$_SESSION['username'] || !$_SESSION['email']){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = strip_tags($username);
$password = strip_tags($password);
$ip = $REMOTE_ADDR;
$domain = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$username=strtolower($username);

if((!$username) || (!$password)){
    echo "You have not submitted one or more fields <br/>";
}else{



///check INFO
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1");
$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);


///other
if ($login_check > '1'){





        ini_set(session.cookie_lifetime, "3600");
        session_register('username');
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        session_register('email_address');
        $_SESSION['email_address'] = $email_address;






         $timestamp = time();
$timeout = $timestamp-$timeoutseconds;
$cool = gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s');
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET lastlogin='$cool' WHERE username='$username'");
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET online='$timestamp' WHERE username='$username'");

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ip='$domain' WHERE username='$username'");



        ?>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content=0;url=mb.php>
<?php

} else {
    echo "wrong username/password combination or account not yet activated<br />
    <br />";
    include 'login.php';
}}}
?>
```

login.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01

Transitional//EN">

<html>
 <head onload="window.status='Welcome To

Mafia'">
  <META name="Maffia"

content="An Online Text Based Mafia Game.">
  <META keywords="mafia, Mafia,

games, text game, base mafia, good games, internet

game, free games, fun, powermad, php games">
  <title>Mafia

</title>
  <link href="global.css" type="text/css"

rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css"

media="screen"><!--
#layer1        { visibility: visible; position: absolute; top:

100px; left: 100px; width: 158px; height: 102px }
#layer2        { visibility: visible; position: absolute; top:

465px; left: 100px; width: 69px; height: 21px }
--></style>

 </head>


<body bgcolor="#000000" text="#FFFFFF" link="#FFFFFF"

vlink="#FFFFFF" alink="#FFFFFF"

onload="document.login.username.focus()">
<form id="login" action="logincheck.php" method="post"

name="login">
  <center>       <tf>
            <center><img border="0" src="logo.jpg" ></center>
            <tr>
            <tr>
            <font size="1"><b><font face="Verdana">Site Best Viewed And Played With FireFox www.mozilla.com 
            <br><br>Hello & Welcome To Bloodtown Mafia Online Multiplayer Game.
            <br> This is not another mafia game but a mafia game with a difference,
            <br> as you play you will realise this game to be very different to others out there.
            <br> New features will be added regularly so that you can enjoy this gaming experience online.
<br>
            <br>
            </font></b></font>
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="30" width="196">
          <div align="center"><font size="1"

face="Verdana"><b>Username:</b></font></div>
</td>
<div align="center"><font size="1"
        <td width="200">
          <input type="text" style="background-color:#000000;

font: 10pt verdana; color:#ffffff; border: 1px solid #900dbf;"

name="username" size="24">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <div align="center"><font size="1"
        <td height="30">
          <div align="center"><font size="1"

face="Verdana"><b>Password:</b></font></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="password"

style="background-color:#000000; font: 10pt verdana;

color:#ffffff; border: 1px solid #900dbf;" name="password"

size="24">

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" height="36">
          <center>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
   <tr><td colspan=2><center>

<center>
              <font size=0.5 face=verdana><b>||<a href="register.php"> Register</a>
              || <a href="lost.php">Lost</a> ||</b></font>
            </center></center></td></tr>
    </table>
  </center>
</form>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no `$REMOTE_ADDR` so thats the one. Use `print_r($_POST);` and see if you are sending the `username` in the post.

Comment: Post your html form/Login form

Answer (score 0):

1. You can replace following line with number 8 line

if (isset($_SESSION['username']) || isset($_SESSION['email'])){

2. There is no variabled defined as **$REMOTE_ADDR**

Please defined a variable before the if condition as defined below.

$REMOTE_ADDR = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

There will be no notice after these changes.

Please let me know, if you still finding any problems

Good luck.